# Sequelize where query with ternary operator

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, orm, sequelize.js

I want to make a `findAll` query with *Sequelize* and I want to pass where conditions dynamically based on parameters rather than writing many `if-else` statements, is there a way to discard a condition if the passed value is null? (See the `[Op.gt]` and `[Op.lte]` below.)

```
Transaction.findAll({
    limit: limit ? limit : 20,
    where: {
        id: id,
        approved: true,
        [Op.gt]: from ? from : null,
        [Op.lte]: to ? to : null
    }
})
```

Running the above code gives this error:

> s.replace is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use spread operator:

```
Transaction.findAll({
    limit: limit || 20,
    where: {
        id: id,
        approved: true,
        ...(from ? { [Op.gt]: from } : {}),
        ...(to ? { [Op.lte]: to } : {})
    }
})
```